# How to get one seperate viewshed raster for each points that are on the same shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, viewshed, visibility, multipoint

I have a shapefile with several points (1 of 30pts and one of 100pts), and I would like to generate a viewshed/field of vision for each point. The objective is to know, for each point, 1) the surface visible from the point, in km², 2) the angle of vision, and 3) how many other points are visible from one.

My first idea was to create 1 shapefile for each point, and run the analysis one by one, but as I have lots of points, it would take lots of time.

Then, I divided the shapefile, so there are only 16 points per shp (as it's the limit of ArcGIS), and I ran an observer point analysis, which you can see on the image. But then, I can't figure out how to classify the data of the raster output to see which pixel is visible from which point and get the data I need.

I'm sure this is an analysis many people had to conduct before, so I'm hoping someone can give me a help, please!

[image: the 16 points observer points raster output]

Comment: This is a problem that requires iteration, if you're not comfortable with python you can use model builder *Iterate Feature Selection* https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00400000000s000000 which will run the process once for each feature in your point layer. To create unique output files for each feature specify the value in the output as an *inline variable* https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_using_inline_variable_substitution/002w0000001t000000/